# How to compile boost/polygon seperately?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

## Problem background:

I am trying to compile [Limbo](https://github.com/limbo018/Limbo) which needs boost/polygon (we could check root/CMakeLists.txt to know this: `find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS polygon`). So I

1. compile the boost following the [step 5](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).
2. Then I get `boost_install/include` and `boost_install/lib` which contain the head files and libraries of sub-components of boost. But I can't find `libboost_polygon**.so` or `libboost_polygon**.a` in `boost_install/lib/`

The problem is, compiling `Limbo` needs `polygon`, but I don't have it, so Cmake error occurs: `could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_polygon" with any of the following names: boost_polygonConfig.cmake ....`, Does anybody know about how to solving this problem? THANKS!

Comment: Did you consider to use some package manager instead building boost yourself? Which platform/compiler are you using?

Comment: Just a thought: Boost 1.55 is around ten years old, if not more. I really hope you're not using that version.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt As the OP does not use the `EXACT` keyword in `find_package` I suppose it's the minimum version required to run the package.

Comment: Thanks pals, I am trying to use the minimum version, i.e. `boost 1.55.0` since the author of this project write the cmake to be compatible with this version. (I am rookie of CMAKE...)

Answer (score 1):

Boost polygon is a **header only** library and does not need to be compiled or built and therefore does not need to be added to the `find_package(Boost ...)` command. Instead use the following form to link against Boost header only libs:

```
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED)
add_library(your_library ....)
target_link_libraries(your_library PUBLIC Boost::headers)
```

To see what Boost libraries are **not** header only see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) for version 1.79

Comment: Thanks, maybe the version of Boost is the problem here, just like @Ulrich Eckhardt mentioned. The project I compiling is based on `the Boost 1.55.0`. So the author configure the `cmake` to be suitable with that version.